# Intalling Ubuntu with Windows 8 on 32 bit System with UEFI

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows-8, uefi

HP530 model, 2007 make, with 32 bit Processor (dual core T2400 by Intel), 945 chipset, and pre-installed Vista.

I upgraded vista to Win8 Pro and left 9GB free for installation of UBUNTU.
It is Safer to assume that Win8 is using UEFI.

The solution for installing Ubuntu requires use of 64 bit version, whereas the processor supports only 32 bit.
Let me know whether I can use the 64 bit version and install it on my 32 bit system, IF not, then the solution is not applicable for my system.

Let me know the solution for 32 bit. I can wait for future version like Ubuntu 13.04 if the matter is expected to be resolved by the new version.

Uninstalling Win8 and reinstalling it in Legacy mode is not an option for me.

This portion was added in response to suggestions:
The  boot info url is http://paste.ubuntu.com/5636872/

Comment: As far as I know, upgrading the OS doesn't affect UEFI.  That's part of the BIOS, right?  And no, you can't install a 64bit OS on a 32bit computer.

Comment: are you sure you are using UEFI? The older laptops doesn't implement UEFI. Even my XPS 15, which I bought last year (came with win7) UEFI was not there. Installing windows 8 doesn't mean it will be on UEFI

Comment: Please indicate your [Boot-Info URL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info), so that we can easily know if you are using UEFI or not.

Comment: The boot info url is http://paste.ubuntu.com/5636872/. IF UEFI is involved, let me know how to dual install ubuntu 12.10.(refer to my original post for details)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your Boot-Info, your Windows8 is not using UEFI (it is installed in Legacy mode). So you must install Ubuntu normally (Legacy mode, not UEFI).

The Boot-Info confirms that your computer is 32bit, so you must install Ubuntu 32bit. (Ubuntu 64bit won't work on this pc)

Comment: Since no UEFI is involved, I will go ahead with installing Ubuntu 12.10 or wait a few days more for 13.04. In case of any issues. Thanks for the prompt help

Comment: I was able to install Ubuntu 12.10. As rightly pointed out, in my case UEFI Was not involved. Thank you